# How would yum ( on centos host ) work with proxy that requires an ssl cert

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, yum

I am trying to setup proxy in /etc/yum.conf with https and ssl cert
Normally, i would have proxy=http://x.x.x.x:80 provided that is the proxy address and since my proxy does not require username and password, that would work. But now i have a requirement, to setup /etc/yum/conf with 
proxy=https://x.x.x.x:433
and the yum hosting centos can only talk to internet via a proxy which accepts ssl cert based Authentication.
So how would i install the ssl Cert on the centos host for yum to work with the proxy host on port 443 and one that requires an SSL Cert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to use the following config directives taken from the yum.conf [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf).

`sslclientcert`

> Path to the SSL client certificate yum should use to connect to
>   repos/remote sites Defaults to none. Note that if you are using curl
>   compiled against NSS (default in Fedora/RHEL), curl treats
>   sslclientcert values with the same basename as *identical*. This
>   version of yum will check that this isn't true and output an error
>   when the repositories "foo" and "bar" violate this, like so:
>   sslclientcert basename shared between foo and bar

`sslclientkey`

> Path to the SSL client key yum should use to connect to repos/remote
>   sites Defaults to none.